# Why does the C++ "Hello World" project generated by Visual Studio look a little strange?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, c++-cli

I'm new to C++ programming (although I have experience in Java, C#, and Visual Basic). I have used Visual Studio 2010 to create a default "Hello World" example project, but when I investigate the sample code it generates, it looks a little bit different from the code that I see when looking at C++ tutorials.

In my investigations, I've learned that there are two versions of C++, or at least two different standards. I think they're called CLR and CLI. What standard or version must I learn to program further in the future?

Comment: "A little bit different"? Hmm, that explains it all.

Comment: I agree that this question could probably be better, but this is a common source of confusion among hopeful new C++ programmers, at least when using Microsoft products (such as Visual Studio). Rather than piling on downvotes, consider trying to improve the question.

Comment: @Cody Gray. Thanks for your reply. And your attitude!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's **regular, plain-old, ISO-standards-based [C++](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++)** which is probably the kind you're seeing in tutorials. If you want to write Windows applications in regular C++, you will probably be [targeting the Win32 API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384843.aspx) (or using a set of classes that wrap the basic functionality of the Win32 API, such as MFC).

Then there's [**C++/CLI**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++/CLI), which can almost be thought of as an entirely new language (albeit a superset of C++) that includes **Microsoft's extensions** in order to support the .NET Framework. It is standardized as [ECMA-372](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-372.htm). The .NET Framework runs on top of the CLR, so the version of C++ that is compatible with the CLR is called "C++/CLI".

You probably want to ignore the C++/CLI variant of the language right now entirely. It's really only useful in interoperability scenarios with .NET code. Since you appear to want to learn C++, the extra CLI stuff is just going to be a confusing distraction. You want to learn *real* C++, not the .NET Framework grafted on top of C++. If you want to learn .NET, start with either C# or VB.NET, instead.

A bit more information on the distinction between C++ and C++/CLI is available in [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5871402/how-important-are-pointers-in-vc-why-does-my-book-not-mention-them/5871718#5871718).

Comment: C++/CLI is a separate, **standardized** language; it is not an "extension" to anything nor is it proprietary.

Answer (score 3):

[c++/cli](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++/CLI) is a dotNET-based language, depending on the [CLR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Language_Runtime).

[C++](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++) is defined by an ISO Standard, and should not be confused with microsoft's c++/CLI

If you wish to work with a dotNET-based language, learn [C#](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_Sharp_%28programming_language%29) not C++/CLI. Most likely your tutorials are for regular C++ - this is a lot more common than C++/CLI. Visual Studio works well with either standard C++ or C++/CLI, you select which to use when creating a project.